Facebook - Scheduled posts on pages via Graph API
I am using Python and Facebook Graph API v17.0 to schedule image posts. I use scheduled_publish_time
parameter when creating the post, also I am specifying published parameter to false. The problem I have is that the post is scheduled but it does not appear in the "facebook planner" (in meta bussines suite).
Even the post is not in the calendar, it is posted in the feed according to date and time specified in the code.
is there a way to access to a specified scheduled post (with the id) and check or edit manually (if is necessary) ?
I tryed with:
https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{post_id}/
But it shows the post with the date and time when it was created not when the post should go live (scheduled date&time).
Do you know how to construct a link to access to a specific scheduled post  that shows the date and time when it should go live (scheduled date&time)?
I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.
